# Show Image from GridView, then slide between the Images

Tags: android, image, gridview

I am currently able to fill a `gridview` with url strings and have an `onClick()` listener that displays the image from the `gridview` in full screen.

**`MainActivity`:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

GridView grid;
LazyAdapter adapter;
public static ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid);

    try {
        new myAsyncTask(this).execute(arrayList).get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    for(int i=0;i<arrayList.size(); i++){
        Log.v("onCreate: ", arrayList.get(i));
    }

    String[]myArray = new String[arrayList.size()];
    myArray = arrayList.toArray(myArray);
    for(int i=0; i<arrayList.size();i++){
        Log.v("myArray", myArray[i]);
    }

    adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, myArray);
    grid.setAdapter(adapter);



    grid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            Log.v("Picture # ", String.valueOf(i));
            Log.v("fsdf", adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString());

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FullScreenImage.class);
            intent.putExtra("id", imageUrl);
            startActivity(intent);



        }
    });
```

**FullScreenImage**

```
public class FullScreenImage extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.full_screen);

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    //int position = intent.getExtras().getInt("id");
    String position = intent.getExtras().getString("id");
    Log.v("FSI==", position);
    ImageView im = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.full_image_view);
    ImageLoader imLo = new ImageLoader(this.getApplicationContext());
    imLo.DisplayImage(position, im);

}

}
```

**DisplayImage in ImageLoader class**

```
public void DisplayImage(String url, ImageView imageView)
{
    imageViews.put(imageView, url);
    Bitmap bitmap=memoryCache.get(url);
    if(bitmap!=null)
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    else
    {
        queuePhoto(url, imageView);
        imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<GridView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/grid"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:horizontalSpacing="6dip"
    android:verticalSpacing="6dip"
    />
```

**item.xml**

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="150dip"
    android:layout_height="150dip"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
```

**full_screen.xml**

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/full_image_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

What I want to do now..

Once you have clicked on an Image, the user should then be able to slide between the images rather than have to go back to the `gridview` to select another.
(I will also want to be adding pinch-zoom, sharing capabilities at some point)

Obviously the parameteres of the method *`DisplayImage`* in the *`ImageLoader`* class required a string Url to be passed to it along with an `ImageView` as this is the method I am using to fill my `GridView`,

I have been playing around with `Fragment`s all day but haven't had much success.

So, I was hoping someone would be able to offer some direction on how to best achieve what I am trying to do. If `fragment`s are the way to go:

- What information do I need to pass from the `FullScreenImage` class to the `FragmentPagerAdapter` class, and then what would be the best way to Display the Image given that my current method requires an `ImageView` parameter rather than a pager?

Hopefully this has made sense and thanks very much in advance for your time and responses,
Kind Regards.